# How to loop cut and specify value without distorting mesh

Tags: modeling

I have a train carriage here:
[image]

And I would like to make a loop cut at the bottom of those seats. I entered a value of 0.4m on the z-axis.

[image]

But this distorts the mesh of the carriage, you can see it's no longer straight:
[image]

How do I add a loop cut where I can specify a value and it does not distort the mesh?

Here is the file if you'd like to investigate:

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your object?

Comment: File uploaded as requested.

Comment: I think you'd need to use Edge slide (G G) after the loop cut to maintain a straight edge. At the moment just altering the Z position of all the edges and keeping the X position the same will create the effect you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, Blender's Snap works with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Edge Slide, on your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> freshly cut loop.

In this projection, snap 'With: Active' (vertex)  and 'To: Edge' is unambiguous:

[image]